# Div vs table to display large set of data

Tags: php, html

We have a custom query section in our software where the client can themself design the query and we will then export it to html table. The problem is if it is more than 1000 rows it is very slow particularly in IE. Query is executed quickly but it takes time to render and even after that when we scroll down it is very slow. Instead of html `table`, my friend suggested me to use `div` element.

Can any one please suggest me before I'm doing big modification please.

Comment: Please clear out this question. "div" is an HTML element <div>..</div>.

Comment: The suggestion must be to use divs instead of table. HTML table will not be rendered until all the data is available while divs are rendered as they come.

Comment: Sorry Frederick it is html table

Comment: Are you using borders on the columns, i'm guessing data has to line up in columns?

Comment: If you're rendering 1000 rows of data, the problem isn't whether you're using a div or a table, but that you're showing a human reader 1000 rows of data. No one reads that much data, either display it in a better format that doesn't require 1000 rows of data, or make this a PDF instead of a "web page". What are you even trying to do here?

Comment: Yes we do have option for exporting to PDF . But they need it in browser just for validating and to make sure each data s correct

Comment: @gwille yes we are using borders

Comment: @Sindhu Vinodhini IE is bad anyway.. if you want to show an user the data as an grid of records (tabular data) then use an table.. div's (divison) isn't designed to be abused like this trust me your going mad with "width: 100px or widh: 10%", float:left;" and "clear: both" problems in IE when you want to format divs like an table....

Answer (score 3):

It's true that, in general, if you use divs instead of tabular elements you will gain performance. That's because, by default, most browsers use an automatic table layout algorithm so that the width of the table and its cells depends on the content thereof.

But if you have tabular data, the semantically correct way of representing is using a table. Then, instead of using divs, you could change the algorithm to be used to layout the tabular elements, using the `table-layout` CSS property:

```
table-layout: fixed
```

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout,

> **table-layout: fixed**
>
> Table and column widths are set by the widths of `table` and `col`
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.
>
> Under the "fixed" layout method, **the entire table can be rendered once
>   the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed
>   up rendering time** over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent
>   cell content may not fit in the column widths provided. Any cell that
>   has content that overflows uses the [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property to determine
>   whether to clip the overflow content.

Comment: From experience with ie I also found having fixed pixel column width for your td elements greatly reduces the time to render.